# Mysql: WHERE statement that depends of the COUNT() of a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've read loads of answers on SO, but still can't get this to work. I'm pretty sure I need a subquery but don't know where I should begin...

Here's readable/psuedo of what i want to do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cat_sub.*, COUNT(job.job_id) AS num_properties_which_meet_criteria
FROM cat_sub
LEFT JOIN job_cat USING (sc_id)
LEFT JOIN job USING (job_id)
WHERE job.village_id=2 AND num_properties_which_meet_criteria > 0
GROUP BY sc_id
```

I'm trying to make my `WHERE` reference the amount of valid results in the `job` table, which in this instance are those which match`job.village_id=2`.

So just to make clear, i don't want the total number of rows matched by the join. I want to total num rows matched by the join and meeting the `WHERE` criteria.

Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You test the value of an aggregate function with a HAVING clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cat_sub.*, COUNT(job.job_id) AS num_properties_which_meet_criteria
FROM cat_sub
LEFT JOIN job_cat USING (sc_id)
LEFT JOIN job USING (job_id)
WHERE job.village_id=2 
GROUP BY sc_id
HAVING COUNT(job.job_id) > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `having` instead of `where`:

```
WHERE job.village_id=2
GROUP BY sc_id 
HAVING num_properties_which_meet_criteria > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cat_sub.*, COUNT(job.job_id)
FROM cat_sub
LEFT JOIN job_cat USING (sc_id)
LEFT JOIN job USING (job_id)
WHERE job.village_id=2 
GROUP BY sc_id 
HAVING COUNT(job.job_id) > 0
```

**UPDATE:** Removed alias

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a "HAVING" clause, there you can use conditions on aggregate functions used in the SELECT part of the query.